# How to run R script on server?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run my R script on a server with 32 CPUs. When I run R on the server and run my script, it only uses one of the CPUs out of 32 CPUS.

Is there any methods to define the number of CPUs should be used with R?

Comment: Look into the `snow` or `parallel` packages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the process you are doing. There are several options how to do parallel computing with R. See the [CRAN Task View: High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).